# .X File Parsing - Call to create Enumeration Object fails

Tags: winapi, parsing, memory-management, directx, enumeration

I'm writing an .X file parser class for DirectX. When I try to parse large files the call to create the enumeration object fails.

I think this is because of the size of the file...the current class works with smaller files such as tiger.x(31 kb). However, when I try to load a larger file such as tiny.x(1500 kb) the call to create enumeration object fails...here is an excerpt from CXParser.cpp:

```
#include "CXParser.h"
#include "d3dx9xof.h"

BOOL CXParser::Parse(char *filename, void** data)
{
    LPD3DXFILE              pDXFile = NULL;
    LPD3DXFILEENUMOBJECT    pEnum = NULL;
    LPD3DXFILEDATA          pDataObj = NULL;
    SIZE_T                  nChildren = NULL;
    DWORD Depth = 0;


int iFileLength=0;
    HANDLE hFile=NULL;
    DWORD dwBytesRead=0;
    LPVOID fileBuffer = NULL;

    hFile = CreateFileA (filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    iFileLength = GetFileSize (hFile, NULL);
fileBuffer = malloc (iFileLength + 2) ;
        ReadFile(hFile, fileBuffer, iFileLength, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    BeginParse(data);
    if(FAILED(D3DXFileCreate(&pDXFile)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create DX File Interface Object", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    if(FAILED(pDXFile->CreateEnumObject((LPVOID)filename, DXFILELOAD_FROMFILE, &pEnum)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create DX Enumeration Object", L"ERROR", MB_OK);           pDXFile->Release();
        return false; // function exits here when loading large .X files

    }
    if(FAILED(pEnum->GetChildren(&nChildren)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Enumerate .X File", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    for(SIZE_T index = 0; index < nChildren; index++)
    {
        if(SUCCEEDED(pEnum->GetChild(index, &pDataObj)))
        {
            if(!pDataObj->IsReference())
            {
                GetObjectName(pDataObj);
                ParseObject(pDataObj, Depth, NULL);
                pDataObj->Release();
            }
        }
    }
    EndParse(data);
    pEnum->Release();
    pDXFile->Release();

    return TRUE;
}
```

My question is this:

Is it possible to load the .X file into a memory buffer before parsing?

Also, I noticed that tiger.x and tiny.x have different number of bits reserved for floating-point values (the headers are diffferent):

tiger.x's header: xof 0302txt 0064

tiny.x's header:  xof 0303txt 0032

Does this difference cause a problem when loading an .X file for enumeration?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the default tiny.x model, I have only seen it fail on enumeration by accidentally specifying an invalid path. I've added file path checking before enumerating (I used boost::filesystem::exists(path)).

I recommend adding such a check, as the code example above doesn't have such an explicit check, so your model could have an invalid name, and thus the error can appear misleading.

Comment: I resolved the file name correctly, its in the same directory as the program (and the same directory as tiger.x)...i'm trying to read the file into memory using CreateFile and ReadFile...I will edit my code above to show what's happening...the fileBuffer is not getting and data from the ReadFile function...